# there an easy way to so a soql query to see the the applications a profile has access to?

Tags: soql, security

I tried this query recently

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM AppMenuItem WHERE Id IN (SELECT SetupEntityId From SetupEntityAccess WHERE Parent.ProfileId =: id) ORDER BY Label
```

and got this error

```
The selected field 'SetupEntityId' in the subquery and the left operand field in the where expression in the outer query 'Id' should point to the same object type
```

I'm trying to do this for a profile such as the id would be the passed in id of the profile

Answer (score 0):

When you compare the ID against the subselect on SetupEntityAccess, you're comparing agains the IDs of SetupEntityAccess, not the SetupEntityId values.

You can't accomplish what you want in a single SQL statement.  You need to retrieve the SetupEntityAccess records, extract the SetupEntityId values, then perform another SQL query on the AppMenuItem using the set of SetupEntityId you've extracted.